# Customize error message in grid view in yii

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii

I want to remove this "404" from the alerting message while deleting a row in grid view , [image]

Answer (score 1):

It means your `ajax` call to delete the row is making `404` error. Make sure that you are calling the right url for delete. You can confirm it by checking the browser console.

**Edit:**

You can use something like `echo "Sorry, Invalid url";` instead of `CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');`

Comment: yeah i know but i have to customize that error message here i am using this Exception 
throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');

Comment: when we use this one ajax respond will be the message we print from that function it cannot be pushed into the browser as a alert. I think i have to customize the delete button in grid view itself.

Comment: You should be able to set up conditional statements in your actionError to handle different error messages as well as differentiate between ajax (e.g., "Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest") and page requests.